# mysql count problems

Tags: mysql, count

```
SELECT count( t1.id ) , t2.special_value
FROM table_1 AS t1, table_2 AS t2
WHERE t1.`group` = 'val'
AND t2.code = 'val'
```

returns

```
count - normal value
special_value - NULL
```

but

```
SELECT t2.special_value
FROM table_2 AS t2
WHERE t2.code = 'val'
```

returns

```
special_value - another normal value
```

why first query works wrong?..

currently, i need

```
(count( t1.id ) + t2.special_value)
```

Comment: How can the first query return `special_value` in columnA. And does the second query return 2 columns?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without knowing anything about your schema, but it appears you haven't defined any relationship between tables t1 and t2, resulting in a cross join. Also, using an aggregate function (count) without any GROUPing is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is why you should never use SQL'89 implicit join syntax.

You have no join condition resulting in a cross join.

Rewrite the query using explicit join syntax:

```
SELECT count( t1.id ) , t2.special_value
FROM table_1 AS t1
INNER JOIN table_2 AS t2 ON (t1.`group` = t2.code)    <<-- join condition here
WHERE ....                                            <<-- filter condition here
GROUP BY ....                                         <<-- group by field here
```

I don't know how table t1 and t2 are linked, so you'll have to tweak this a bit, but that's how it supposed to work.
And please never ever use implicit `where` joins again.

**Remarks**
I'm wondering what `` p.`group` `` and `pp.code` are, but I'm guessing you meant to write `` t1.`group` `` and `t2.code`

You only need to escape fields and tablenames in `` ` `` backticks if they are reserved words.
Personally all those backticks make me dizzy, but that's just me.

Comment: @Johan: it's not just you. I would have downvoted the question only for that, if only I hadn't reached my daily limit...

Comment: t2.special_value returns NULL if count(t1.id) = 0

Comment: @Zdomb, only if you use a `left join` not on an inner join.

Comment: using `group by t2.group`now returns empty result if count(t1.id) = 0

Comment: @zdomb, of course it does if count=0 there are no rows and there's nothing to group by. replace the `inner join` with a `left join`.

Comment: @Zdomb, you need to have a field on both tables that you can **join** on, please read: http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/  The fact that you have count=0 is proof that there are **no** fields that meet the join criteria. I cannot help you because I don't know your tables, only you do.